# MongoDB aggregation: How to restructure data so that the lookup data is root data but contains some data from the parent?

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

MongoDB aggregation: How to restructure data so that the lookup data is root data but contains some data from the parent?

Lets say I have data that looks as shown below:

```
// posts data
[
  {
    "_id":"62a25c932c38e92bdcd32094",
    "text": "Text to be written by the creator of the post.",
    "userId": "621b814eed5b141c19c2d34b"
    "createdAt": {
      "$date": "2022-06-09T20:48:19.528Z"
    },
  }
]
```

.

```
// comments data
[
  {
    "_id": {
      "$oid": "62a3677843c638676e126815"
    },
    "postId": {
      "$oid": "62a25c932c38e92bdcd32094"
    },
    "text": "Text to be written by the creator of the comment.",
    "userId": {
      "$oid": "6255d5d7eb15644e44b84240"
    },
    "createdAt": {
      "$date": "2022-06-10T15:47:04.429Z"
    }
  }
]
```

.

```
// likes data 
[
  {
    "_id": {
      "$oid": "62a30565f8ded22defc7bb78"
    },
    "postId": {
      "$oid": "62a25c932c38e92bdcd32094"
    },
    "userId": {
      "$oid": "6255d5d7eb15644e44b84240"
    },
    "createdAt": {
      "$date": "2022-06-10T08:48:37.203Z"
    }
  },
]
```

}
]

I want to create an aggregation pipeline that returns each comment as its own document and each like as its own document. The returned documents should also contain post data.

For example for the data given above the returned data would look like so:

```
[
  {
    "_id":"62a25c932c38e92bdcd32094",
    "text": "Text to be written by the creator of the post.",
    "userId": "621b814eed5b141c19c2d34b"
    "comment":{
        "_id": {
          "$oid": "62a3677843c638676e126815"
        },
        "user":{
          "name": "John"
        }
    }
    "createdAt": {
      "$date": "2022-06-09T20:48:19.528Z"
    },
  },
  {
    "_id":"62a25c932c38e92bdcd32094",
    "text": "Text to be written by the creator of the post.",
    "userId": "621b814eed5b141c19c2d34b"
    "like":{
        "_id": {
          "$oid": "62a30565f8ded22defc7bb78"
        },
        "user":{
          "name": "John"
        }
    }
    "createdAt": {
      "$date": "2022-06-09T20:48:19.528Z"
    },
  }
]
```

Answer (score 0):

This feels a bit "hacky" so hopefully you'll get a better answer, but here's one way you could do it.

N.B.:  I couldn't find `"user":{"name": "John"}` in your collections so I gave you `"userId"` instead.

```js
db.posts.aggregate([
  {
    "$match": {
      "_id": ObjectId("62a25c932c38e92bdcd32094")
    }
  },
  {
    "$lookup": {
      "from": "comments",
      "localField": "_id",
      "foreignField": "postId",
      "pipeline": [
        {"$project": {"userId": 1}}
      ],
      "as": "comments"
    }
  },
  {
    "$lookup": {
      "from": "likes",
      "localField": "_id",
      "foreignField": "postId",
      "pipeline": [
        {"$project": {"userId": 1}}
      ],
      "as": "likes"
    }
  },
  {"$unwind": "$comments"},
  {"$unwind": "$likes"},
  {
    "$set": {
      "unwindMe": [
        {"comment": "$comments"},
        {"like": "$likes"}
      ]
    }
  },
  {"$unwind": "$unwindMe"},
  {"$unset": ["comments", "likes"]},
  {
    "$replaceWith": {
      "$mergeObjects": ["$$ROOT", "$unwindMe"]
    }
  },
  {"$unset": "unwindMe"}
])
```

Try it on [mongoplayground.net](https://mongoplayground.net/p/3Dk1ewa7tkw).